# Get placeId of state from city in here geocode api

Tags: here-api

I have a problem with geocoding states and citys in Germany. I'm not able to get the correct place id for specific countys or states. Lets take a county for example: Oldenburg.

Oldenburg county exists twice inside the Here API.

1. `Oldenburg (Oldb.)` - which is the county from the city Oldenburg
2. `Oldenburg` - which is the county from the area around the city of Oldenburg

So i'd now like to defer between booth unique Oldenburg-Countys. But therefore, i need the correct `herePlaceId` for booth countys. But i'm not able to form the correct request for the here-api, so that i'm getting the correct placeId for booth of them. `Oldenburg (Oldb.)` as county for the city Oldenburg works fine, but how would it be possible to get the correct `herePlaceId` for `Oldenburg`, the county around Oldenburg-City.

Google understands my search correctly:

This is county `Oldenburg` for the area around Oldenburg-City: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Oldenburg/@52.9845275,8.0922129,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47b72f168effaa95:0xd6a3061c95f9bd2b!8m2!3d52.9654037!4d8.386907

and this is the County `Oldenburg (Oldb.)` for the city itself: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Oldenburg/@53.0578722,8.3356219,11.25z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47b6de53b5b669b3:0xed1ccb1bad854865!8m2!3d53.1434501!4d8.2145521

I hope you are understanding what i mean. As a second example you can take `Sachsen`. Whenever you request `Sachsen` to the here-geocoding-api you will get back a city in south-germany and no information about the state `Sachsen`.

Is there a way to get only information for states back from the api?

```
[
  {
    formattedAddress: 'Sachsen bei Ansbach, Bayern, Deutschland',
    latitude: 49.28949,
    longitude: 10.66038,
    country: 'Deutschland',
    countryCode: 'DE',
    state: 'Bayern',
    county: 'Ansbach (Landkreis)',
    city: 'Sachsen bei Ansbach',
    zipcode: '91623',
    district: null,
    streetName: null,
    streetNumber: null,
    building: null,
    extra: { herePlaceId: 'NT_jFqf4FFetzruKjei6.HGfA', confidence: 1 },
    administrativeLevels: { level1long: 'Bayern', level2long: 'Ansbach (Landkreis)' },
    provider: 'here'
  }
]
```

**Edit - 14.04.2020 | 13:23Uhr**
As i played around with the api i found out that i can get the correct placeId for `Sachsen` by using a english request. So i didn't request `Sachsen, Deutschland` but `Saxony, Germany`, that did it, i got the correct placeId for state `Sachsen`. Problem with `Oldenburg` still exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of achieving this:

---

**1. If you know you're searching exactly for country or state or county, etc., you can use [Geocoder API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/resource-geocode.html):**

For **Oldenburg** county case (result is 2 counties): https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?&county=Oldenburg&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY

For **Sachsen** state case (result is 1 state): https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?&state=Sachsen&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY

---

**2. If you don't know the query type, you can use [Geocoder Autocomplete API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoding_suggestions) which gives you multiple suggestions and you can filter those by `matchLevel` property.** In your Oldenburg case, `matchLevel`should equal `"county"`:

For **Oldenburg** county case (with max 5 results):
https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=Oldenburg&maxresults=5&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY

The response contains 5 results, two of those have property `"matchLevel": "county"`:

- **Deutschland, Oldenburg (Oldb.)**
- **Deutschland, Oldenburg**

```
.
.
{
  "label": "Deutschland, Oldenburg (Oldb.)",
  "language": "de",
  "countryCode": "DEU",
  "locationId": "NT_UgRRHQATr.tTMA-5pu0KcC",
  "address": {
    "country": "Deutschland",
    "state": "Niedersachsen",
    "county": "Oldenburg (Oldb.)"
  },
  "matchLevel": "county"
},
{
  "label": "Deutschland, Oldenburg",
  "language": "de",
  "countryCode": "DEU",
  "locationId": "NT_NrK.-.wF217Ne36759bEwC",
  "address": {
    "country": "Deutschland",
    "state": "Niedersachsen",
    "county": "Oldenburg"
  },
  "matchLevel": "county"
},
.
.
```

---

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Sithys did my answer help?